# Why HEVC playback on Linux and Windows is different?

Tags: windows-7, linux, video, vlc-media-player, h.265

I have an old 2.7 GHz Dual Core machine on a DG41RQ motherboard, with 4 GB RAM. I tried to play a x265 encoded video (1080p) with VLC on Windows 7. The video was choppy and was lagging, while audio was normal (Because of codecs). Although, with Zorin OS(Ubuntu based Linux), VLC played the same file without any issues whatsoever. What can be the reason?

Comment: You didn't list your Graphics device ( like Nvidia, AMD, Intel ). Could be the Windows© driver is missing? I.e. your Linux OS seems to have done the Graphics setup automatically ....

Comment: The graphic card is Intel HD(R) graphic card on Intel G41 Express chip set. There are no dedicated graphic card/memory installed on my system. It is a pretty old system though.

Comment: Would be strange if the right driver isn't installed with Windows 7? Anyway, here it is https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=w7+Intel+HD(R)+graphic+card+on+Intel+G41+Express

Comment: Well, they are the right drivers, and of course latest. I just cannot figure out how linux handles the video. I think maybe this is due to allocation of resources or something, but I needed someone to explain to me how it happens. Thanks for your reply though Knud.